# Independence of residuals over time

Tags: r, regression, time-series, residuals, model

My plots of conditional weighted residuals (CWRES) plotted against time show some sort of time trend (image attached). The response variable is on a Box_cox scale. How could I solve this problem ? [image]

Comment: "Box-Cox scale" isn't precise enough to indicate what you did, but some transformation of the response is implied. But Box-Cox does not purport to do anything to remove time trend. The time trend here seems slight. Whether (a) it is a side-effect of the transformation (b) you should modify your model to match the time trend (c) you can just ignore it -- or some combination -- is not something on which we can easily advise on this little information.

Comment: In addition, not that appearance of trend can be  sensitive to how and how much you smooth.